# A colon after foreach loop statement cause an error

Tags: php

I got below code

```
<?php foreach ( $resultsb as $optionb ) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $optionb->bID; ?>"><?php echo $optionb->book;?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i know how the `foreach` is working here but i didn't get the `:` after the php statement what does the `:` do after the `foreach` statement

Comment: Whenever you get an error and ask for help, ADD THE ERROR MESSAGE!

Comment: `foreach() :` and `endforeach;` ar synonyms for `foreach() {}`.
Your code looks fine though. What is the error?

Comment: @TobiasKun you should post it as the answer because that's what the OP is confused about.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Thx for the tip. Thought there is something else missing because of the "error"-headline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($resultsb as $optionb) : ?>
    ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

is nothing else then:

```
<?php foreach($resultsb as $optionb) { ?>
    ...
<?php } ?>
```

IMO it enhances the readability in files with a lot of html/xml etc.

Comment: "Enchancing readability" in spaghetti code sounds kind like oxymoron.

Comment: Yes that is correct. But the alternative with curly braces is even worse :D

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17);

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "Current value of \$a: $v.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is true. You must check your array. Error not related to ":". It related to your $resultsb.